# Bash doesn't execute MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, bash

I've connected to my MySQL database in a docker container using:

```
docker exec -it ti4-automation-mysql-1 bash
```

And I've logged in using:

```
mysql -u root -p ti4-automation
```

If I want to perform a command:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I get this:

[image]

It looks like the `;` doesn't end the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\s` which will give the following output and verify the `Using delimiter:`  line

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          45
Current database:       my_database
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.34-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 16 days 22 hours 19 min 37 sec
```

Answer (score -1):

you should you this command its work well in mysql docker container

```
mysql -u user -p -e 'show databases;'
```